# Enumerate over all attributes of a class in python

Tags: python, enumeration

How do I enumerate over all attributes and instances of a class in Python?

This is the class:

```py
class Human:
    def __init__(self, name, age, gender):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.gender = gender
```

This can't be a duplicate. I basically want to get a dictionary of all attributes name and their values and loop over the dictionary.

Comment: Attributes and instances are very different things...

Comment: You want `vars`; not sure of the best dup target (unless you're actually interested in finding all instances from the class. Ask that separately then, the answers are very different)

Comment: Get the dictionary using __dict__. Create an instance of the class : `human = Human("Name", 123, "M")` then get the dictionary using `human.__dict__`

Comment: NewbieProgrammer, Thanks for your help. That indeed worked for me. Make it as an answer so that I can mark it.

Comment: @Roshan... My answer has it plus a pointer to Python dataclasses.

Answer (score 0):

Every class has a `__dict__` attribute which is a dictionary of all its attributes (plus some other special fields beginning with a double underscore.

So you can loop through `__dict__` and ignore the keys starting with underscore.

You can also skip over `callables` if you just want attributes.

But may be you should be using a `dataclass`.

Comment: Thanks.. I didn't know about dataclasses at all. You get an upvote :)

Comment: Great. Upvotes back to 0 now :D